# If a callback calls the enclosing function, would it be called a recursive call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

For example:

If `http.request` call is made in `res.on('end')` callback, then is the call recursive?

```
http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function(){
    //do some stuff
    http.request(options, function(res) {...});//is this recursive?
  });
}).end();
```

Edit:

Let's take a simpler example: suppose there is a function which reads a file character by character:

```
var noOfChar = 10;
var i = 0;
readChar(function processChar(char){
  if(i < noOfChar) {
    console.log(char);
    i++;
    readChar(processChar); //is this recursive?
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is recursive... a recursive call is when a method is called again... in this case the outer code is not executed again

Comment: It isn't recursive, it is just calling another http.request, for it to be recursive the initial http.request would have to set to a variable, and that variable would need to be called within itself.  So it isn't calling an identical looking function but actually the same function. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @ArunPJohny but the `http.request` will be executed again, only the callback function may be different.

Comment: @Anurag Peshne for a call to be recursive a function must call itself.

Comment: @zerkms in this case the function is executing a code which calls the function, would this be considered as calling itself?

Comment: @AnuragPeshne nope, in your code your anonymous function calls something else.

Comment: @zerkms: I have added another example, a simpler one. Here a callback calls the enclosing function.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne it's not "simpler", it's different. That one **is** a recursion

Answer (score 3):

Rather than arguing about what to label it, let's consider some concrete attributes of your code, and how it is similar or different to what people usually mean by "recursive".

Usually a recursive function is something that grows the stack at each step (except for tail-call recursion, which uses a trick to prevent that growth). But in node, an asynchronous callback discards the stack of the outside context. (Try raising an exception inside the callback and see for yourself.) So this code does not grow the stack.

Also usually a recursive function is something that calls itself, but I don't see that happening anywhere in your example. The two listeners on `http` are different functions.

The second example doesn't call itself directly, but it does call itself indirectly. You have a "base case" (`noOfChar >= 10`) at which point the recursion unwinds. If `readChar` were synchronous you'd even be growing the stack. So this seems closer to recursive.

Notice that in your second example you have a named function, whereas the first example has only anonymous functions. In general I don't think recursion is possible without a named function (or at least some variable that holds the function), because otherwise how can a function refer to itself?

Comment: +1 for mentioning tail-recursion, it helped me to realise recursion has to do more with how problem is solved rather than maintaining stacks. Also I learned something new: anonymous recursion, maybe you too will find it interesting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_recursion

Comment: I'd +1 if you remove the last paragraph: [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) does not bind event handlers to `http`, instead it creates a new request on every call.

Comment: @Bergi Oh you're right. It's been a while since I've done node. . . . :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll be recursive if you are going to pass a different `callback` to it.

If you will pass same `callback` to both, it is going to be recursive.

**Recursive** means if I'm calling the same function in function definition itself. But if you are going to pass different callbacks it will be something like bellow.

Suppose you have 2 different callbacks `callback1 and callback2`.

You have passed first callback to outer `http.request` and second callback to inner `http.request`, so outer `http.request` will be executing the code given in `callback1` but the inner will be executing code given in `callback2`.

Comment: Not even then it would be recursive, as `http.request` is asynchronous. Standard "recursion" is accociated with a call stack and a return value, which are not found here.

Comment: @Bergi do you mean no async function can be recursive.

Comment: @Bergi please correct me if I'm wrong but to have closures JavaScript uses 'Heap' for functions. If we associate recursion with call stack then we can't call any function recursive (even those without callbacks).
Also the outer function will be 'in memory' until the call backs are done.
I'm fairly new to all this, please let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: @Mritunjay: Yes. I've heard the terms "semi-recursive" and "pseudo-recursive" for functions that call themselves from their own asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne: Yes, scopes that need to be persisted because of closure go on the heap. However, not all functions need this - it's in fact a great compiler optimisation game what to put where. But regardless, even when data is put on the heap, all function calls do form a call stack; storing where to return. Asynchronous callbacks ("continuations") don't do that - even if they store in closure which actions to perform, they have no stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the meaning of the question.
Will you be flogged to death by your boss if the answer is yes?
Is there a law against recursivity?

`http.request` is only a means to an end. One way or another, you will need to call it more than once to process a transaction.
The trouble with your example code is that you handle an asynchronous exchange in one big lump of code, which handles the response directly without tracking the state of the transaction.

The only comment that comes to my mind is that this kind of logic is extremely fragile, because the termination conditions are dependent on whatever parameters are passed to your requests, leaving the door open to a score of potential problems like out of sync answers and infinite loops (whether they deserve the name of "recursive calls" is of little interest if they hang the system in the end).

I would rather advise to build an explicit state machine to track the progress of intended HTTP exchanges, which would dispense of philosophical questions about recursivity and the associated "good practices".

Comment: yes, you are right, this is a very bad way of doing things. But I was just curious to know, maybe it will help me to understand internal working of language.

Comment: Well "recursive" can have different meanings. Applied to a function as a language element, your example is not recursive because the actual invokation of http.request will be done later in a callback. Applied to the process as a whole, it might be recursive if you enter a loop that plays the same sequence of requests without a termination condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer my own question because I think now I understand Recursion a bit better. Maybe this will help someone else.

My doubt was if a function invokes a callback, which calls the function again would it be called recursion. I feel it is similar to [indirect recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Indirect_recursion) where function1 calls function2 and function2 calls function1 again. So it doesn't matter if function1 calls function2 which calls function3 which in turn call function1 again, it is still recursive. In the same way it shouldn't matter if function invokes a callback which invokes another callback which calls the function. If second example is recursive, first can also be recursive.

Recursive solution to a problem has to do more with how the problem is solved than the language implementation like growth of stack. Take `tail-recursion` for consideration, it doesn't increase call stack, yet no ones questions about it's recursiveness.

So the key point is to think recursively. Take the whole problem, if a part of it can be solved in the same way as the original problem then the solution is **Recursive**. A function calling itself may not qualify for being recursive. Some may call it self referencing functions but not recursive.

Recursion should at least consist of a base case and a recursive case, each self-reference should bring the input value closer to the base case which would end the recursion.So I think **both of the examples mentioned in the question are not recursive**.

Recursive calls may not result in increase in call stack. There is tail call recursion which keeps call stack size constant.

Take the following examples which consist of callbacks, here outer function stack frame may or may not be in memory.

```
var input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

function double(ip) { 
  return ip.map(function (element) {
    if(Array.isArray(element)) {
      return double(element);
    }
    else {
      return 2 * element;
    }
  });
}

console.log(double(input));
```

I would call it as recursive. Also we can do [Anonymous Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_recursion), so explicitly naming a function isn't necessary.